# Convert SQL to SQLite in an easy way?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite

My question: has someone a super-easy way to convert a SQL-file in SQLite?

Comment: Define "a SQL-file."  Do you mean a file containing SQL commands, or something else about the database?

Comment: this question is vague and confusing and you should put some more detail into it so people understand what you're talking about

Comment: Do you mean "convert a file of SQL statements into a form that's compatible with SQLite?" You'd need to specify the source SQL flavour then: MySQL? MSSQL Server? PostgreSQL? Firebird? Oracle? Yummy?

Comment: Well I have a database... A file, it has the *.sql ending and it contains stuff (I'm super dumb with these internetlanguages). I want to try to use it in offline-mode on my iPhone. As far as I know I will have to convert it to SQLite.

Comment: Well I forgot the flavour: it's MySQL ;)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, now it's a little clearer: You want to take an existing MySQL file and translate it into its SQL Lite equivalent.

There are two parts to this process:

1. Translate the DDL from one SQL database to another (DDL == "Data Definition Language")
2. Migrate data from one schema to another.

Every SQL vendor starts with ANSI SQL and adds in their own proprietary syntax.  So you'll have to create a SQL Lite schema (tables, columns, indexes, etc) from the MySQL definition.

The data migration process is called ETL ("Extract-Transform-Load").  You might have to massage some of that data from MySQL to get it into SQL Lite.

The best scenario would be to export your MySQL data into a .csv file, create the table in SQL Lite, then import the .csv file.

Comment: Thanks 100times! That sounds easy :)

Comment: Just to add to the subject... there are DB abstraction layers like ADODB that can be used to write your SQL in a standard way so it can be run in different envirionments. EG: you could move from MySQL to Oracle by changing a connection script, and not have to rewrite your queries. Don't know if it supports SQL-Lite, but something to think about if you're moving platforms often...

Comment: thanks duffymo, just one more question: is there a better way to create a sqlite.db, than just using the terminal?... I have a gigantic database...

Comment: What do you mean by "gigantic"?  Number of tables/columns or amount of data stored in the schema?  In both cases, I'd recommend that you script the creation of the schema and the database.  If by "better way" you mean something that will allow you to do it without effort, the answer is "no".  You'll just have to pick up a shovel and get to work.