# Import .sql file into sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a `.sql` file with `insert statements` in `C:\sqldata\MyData.sql`. I need to insert data into `sqlite` database in my Android App using this `.sql` file.

How could I do this?

Comment: use file Connection API, open .sql file, read insert statements and insert data into database :)

Comment: You can do it using a process called ETL. See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555261/convert-sql-to-sqlite-in-an-easy-way

Comment: At fist you need it to put into the directory res/raw. The other stuff you will find easyly

Comment: I have found answer for my question from [here](http://www.michenux.net/android-database-sqlite-creation-upgrade-245.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

Comment: Is this an Android app for your own personal use or one which you plan to distribute?

Answer (score 0):

First of all download sqlite browser or equivalent software and execute your create-insert statements. then follow that [tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)(which is an awesome tutorial)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728